# How to stop loading container untill execute Parent UIviewcontroller code?

Tags: swift

I have a root viewController(v1) and Second UIViewController(v2). v2 showing on button click and v2 have container(c1). My problem is when I called v2 then c1 also load at same time but I need to load c1 after executing v2 function completely. In v2 I am fetching value from database so its taking some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to right code in  func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)  method in child container which get executed after parent complete his loading code

```
func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
// code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of stopping the container loading, add a delegate to your child controller which V2 will call once the V2 has completed its loading.

```
@protocol LoadingDelegate {
   func didFinishLoading()
}

class ViewController V2 {

     func viewDidLoad() {
         childController.delegate = self
     }

     func finishedProcessing() {
      // Finsihed processing 
         delegate. didFinishLoading()
     }
}


class ChildController<LoadingDelegate> {
     func didFinishLoading() {
         // Do your stuff here
     }
}
```

Till the time V2 is doing its loading you can show a activity indicator in child controller